# Will "Individual ECG findings" be understood as "ECG findings presented on a per-individual basis"?

Tags: word-meaning, translation

There's a table in a document I'm translating: it provides ECG data on patients receiving a drug. The columns are: code of patient (his unique ID), age of patient, date of ECG test, results of ECG test. There are several ECG test results per patient (taken over a year).

If I translate the name of the table word-by-word from Russian as "**Individual** ECG findings", would this be understood as "ECG findings per **individual patient**", or would this be understood as "standalone ECG findings"?

I mean, would the adjective "individual" be understood by the reader as "related to this or that particular individual" or rather as "findings considered separately (individually) from other findings"?

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/individual#british-1-2-1):

> [image]

Maybe I'm "over-thinking" this issue, and the sentence could easily be understood both ways, depending on the context?

Comment: Why not just say "per-patient"?

Comment: @JohnFeltz - I thought of this exact phrase, and omitted the mention of it specifically to check whether it would be proposed by a native speaker. Do you think it would be better than "individual findings"? I might use it then. Frankly, I think that in my context even "individual" would be understood, since the table contents are plain, but still this issue started to nag me. (0:

Comment: "Individual" findings, without more context, is vague.  If I had patient data from 15 hospitals, then "individual" could refer to the hospitals.  If you want to refer to patients, use per-patient; if you want to refer to the hospitals, use per-hospital.  Then there is no ambiguity.  "Individual" can mean "human being", and it can also mean "single instance of something"

Comment: @JohnFeltz - ah, so it can mean both. That is at least better than if it meant only "standalone findings". But yes, for clarity's sake "per-patient" would be better. Thank you.

Comment: I would wonder what **individual** meant there.  I would expect simply "ECG Findings". The table would be clearer without the word. It's on the patient row.  If the person reading the table doesn't understand that the findings relate to the ECG taken on that patient on that date, they are in the wrong profession.

Comment: @TRomano - thank you for your comment! My colleagues quoted from the [ICH E3 Guideline](https://goo.gl/F9sRdB): "Listing of **Individual** Laboratory Measurements **by Patient**". I agree that dropping the word "individual" would be okay, but as a translator one becomes wary of dropping too much of the original wording, especially in highly regulated documents.

Comment: I don't see anything in that document (e.g. circa p. 25) that would require the word "individual" to appear as a column label. The table doesn't include more than one ECG test per row, does it?

Comment: @TRomano - it has several rows with ECG test results per each patient, but yes, a single row does contain only a single ECG result (mostly there's only an indication that the result is "okay"). I'm reading this guideline now, but I'm on page 7 thus far.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase you are looking for is

> Individual ECG findings by patient

assuming your table is setup so the multiple readings of a single patient are grouped together and possibly sorted by date.

"Individual" in this case would mean a single ECG measurement as opposed to an average of the measurements which might have been used for each patient.